# Last published date in Items table in Broker Database

Tags: 2013, broker

I want to know where we are setting last published date in Broker Database in tridion 2013.
Are we setting this in some Tridion DLL or Date.Now in stored procedure.

Comment: Why is it important to know this exactly? You are aware that the broker database, its datamodel and data layer are basically a black box and therefore it should not be of any importance to you how what is set where?

Comment: It is set by the deployer, at time of publishing. As Bart says, I'm not really sure why you would need to know this :)

Comment: We are using DD4T here and while pushing the XML to broker, we need to set the lastpublisheddate of component . I dont know if it is possible or not in DD4T.

Comment: Delivery doesn't store Components per se, but rather Pages and Component Presentations and Custom Metadata. You can always (and probably should if using DD4T) add the date with a template. And even then be careful with what this date means. Publish date depends on publishing, if you need author control or if having the same date across all CPs is not desired (as in a bulk publishing scenario) then the date should be in a field instead.

Comment: DD4T uses the regular publishing pipeline, so the last published data in the Broker database will be set for you automatically.

Comment: *we need to set the lastpublisheddate of component* - Why? It sounds like you're talking about setting the last published date of the Component when you Publish the Page? Why do you need to do this? Can't you use some custom Component metadata and set it via the events system instead of abusing internal fields?

Comment: Were you able to get or implement this date information in delivery? I think the above comments answered the question (deployer per Nuno and Broker db per Frank), otherwise please post a follow-up on the answer that worked for this question. Thanks!